# Converting kotlin DSL back to groovy?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, groovy, build.gradle

I'm having a difficult time figuring out the syntax for any of this. I'd love to be able to convert my groovy gradle file to kotlin, but it's 400+ lines and that's not feasible at the moment.

I'd like to know how to write this kotlin code in groovy:

```
filteringConfiguration {
        whitelist {
            add(SimpleClassnameFilter(".*".toRegex()))
        }
        blacklist {
            add(SimpleClassnameFilter("$^".toRegex()))
        }
    }
    testClassRegexes = listOf("^((?!Abstract).)*Test$")
    includeSerialRegexes = emptyList()
    excludeSerialRegexes = emptyList()
```

Comment: Hmm... Apparently most people want to go [the other way](https://www.google.com/search?q=kotlin+to+groovy), from groovy to kotlin.

Comment: I would like to as well, but that's not possible at the moment. I'd also be happy if the library I'm using had documentation for both kotlin and groovy.

Comment: How come? Is there an error when using the it's build? Maybe we could try to fix that?

Comment: I am in the same position, we just started with kotlin but we can't get the multi project build setup to be recognized on vs code. Started to do the top level in groovy, and surprise, it starts working. But luckily our code isn't as complicated. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark:

```
filteringConfiguration {
    whitelist {
        add(new SimpleClassnameFilter(/.*/))
    }
    blacklist {
        add(new SimpleClassnameFilter(/$^/))
    }
}
testClassRegexes = [/^((?!Abstract).)*Test$/]
includeSerialRegexes = []
excludeSerialRegexes = []
```

Comment: Needs to be Test\$ instead of Test$, and gradle has no idea what SimpleClassnameFilter is, but this is a great help!

Comment: ... or slashy strings. I'd assume you would have to import those and i assumed they are already imported (for the plugin you where taling about).

Comment: It's a class in the gradle plugin that uses this configuration code, but either the syntax is wrong or my IDE just doesn't feel like acknowledging it. Unfortunately my background knowledge of this part of gradle is lacking.